# Why Error Boundary is handled by a Component and not a Higher Order Component (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I just read [the React documentation about Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) and it's said that we can use it as a regular component, and therefore wrap the component this way :

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <MyWidget />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

But I thought this is typically the use of a Higher Order Component if I clearly understood [@Robin Wieruch's lesson](https://www.robinwieruch.de/gentle-introduction-higher-order-components/) :

> Higher order components usually take a component and optional arguments as input and return an enhanced component of the input component.

What do you think ? What would be the proper way to do ?

Comment: Well a HOC also return a component so there's no difference as far as react is concerned. HOC is just a design pattern to abstract away common functionality ( error handling maybe ). Hope this helps !

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a "typical HOC" here. There is an API provided by React to specifically facilitate the handling of children. With a HOC that takes in a component class, you don't have nearly the freedom with the children.

Comment: @Li357 Error handling looks like 'enhancing a component' for me in that example, justifying the fact to make use of a 'typical HOC' if I follow Robin Wieruch's definition. If it doesn't make sense there, then where does it makes sense ? (real question, no sarcasm in it ! :) )

Comment: @arnaudambro If you're explicitly wrapping a component in something such as giving it access to state to a component (redux) or navigation state (react-navigation). If you don't know the children ahead of time an HOC doesn't make sense

Comment: Understood your point. So as an example, I am using the `react-timeout` library to use timeOuts in React properly, seems to work fine. It happens that the `ReactTimeout` component _has been developed_ as a HOC, whereas it doesn't know ahead of time its children (it can be any children of any kind). Is it a mistake from the developer or a misunderstanding from my part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 years later, I think I just understood what I misunderstood: React's example is not about creating a wrapper Component handling errors, neither a HOC or whatever, it's just a how-to introducing `getDerivedStateFromError` and `componentDidCatch` methods.